# Dados não estão sendo excluidos do banco de dados

Tags: php

Fiz um form, onde, quando o usuário clicar no botão excluir, o valor inserido no imput 'id', seja excluido do banco de dados. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

Segue meu formulario.

```
  <form name="Form_CRUD" method="post" action="consulta.php" >
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="hidden" id="id_input" class="form-control" name="id">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome_input" class="form-control" name="nome">

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Sobrenome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sobrenome_input" name="sobrenome">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="Add"  class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
        <button type="submit" name="Upd" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
        <button type="submit" name="Del" class="btn btn-primary">Excluir</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php

    $validarenvio = isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : '';

    if ($validarenvio == '1') :
    ?>

        <div class=" alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <strong>Sucesso!</strong>
            Cadastro realizado com sucesso
        </div>
        <?php  endif; ?>
    <?php
    if($validarenvio == '2'):
    ?>

        <div class=" alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>Sucesso!</strong>
            Alterado com sucesso!
        </div>

    <?php  endif; ?>
    <?php
    if($validarenvio == '3'):
    ?>

        <div class=" alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>Sucesso!</strong>
            Excluido com sucesso!
        </div>

    <?php  endif; ?>
    <?php
    if($validarenvio == '0'):
    ?>

        <div class=" alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>Erro!</strong>
            Erro de envio verifique!
        </div>

    <?php  endif; ?>
```

Segue minha consulta.php:

```
                    <?php
                    require_once ('classes/conecta.php'); 
                    $idCli = trim($_POST['id']);
                    $nomeCli = trim($_POST['nome']);
                    $sobrenomeCli = trim($_POST['sobrenome']);
                    $insert = "INSERT INTO clientes_cli";
                    $insert .= " (nome_cli, sobrenome_cli)";
                    $insert .= "VALUES ('$nomeCli', '$sobrenomeCli')";
                    $Obj_Conexao = new CONEXAO();

                    $erro = 0;
                    $up = "UPDATE clientes_cli";
                    $up .= " SET nome_cli = '$nomeCli', sobrenome_cli = '$sobrenomeCli'";
                    $up .= "WHERE cod_cli = $idCli";

                    $del = "DELETE From clientes_cli";
                    $del .= "WHERE cod_cli = $idCli";



                    if (isset($_POST['Add'])){
                            header('Location: index.php?s=1');
                            $inserir_dados = $Obj_Conexao->Consulta($insert);
                            exit;
                    } else if (isset($_POST['Upd'])) {
                            header('Location: index.php?s=2'); 
                            $alterar_dados = $Obj_Conexao->Consulta($up);
                            exit;
                    } else if (isset($_POST['Del'])){
                            header('Location: index.php?s=3'); 
                            $Deletar_dados = $Obj_Conexao->Consulta($del);
                            exit;
                    } else {
                            header('Location: index.php?s=0'); 
                            exit;
                    }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Qual retorno vc esta obtendo desta operação?

2- Operações de DELETE devem ser feitas sempre com o campo PK da tabela por motivo de segurança. Este campo 'cod_cli' e a PK de sua tabela? Caso não seja verifique nas configs do seu DB se esta permitindo exclusão sem usar PK.

3- O ideal seria realizar a exclusão ANTES do header location!

Comment: Gabriel, sim minha 'cod_cli' é minha PK sim.

Comment: Fiz a alteração  do seu item três e não funfou!

Comment: A mensagem ao usuario está respondendo confome o programado. Mas no banco de dados não ocorre nenhuma ação.